# Can caliper skip some Param combinations for some methods?

Tags: java, benchmarking, caliper

I'm testing 6 different implementations of a two methods, which would need `time*` 12 method. Using an interface and `@Param` with a `Supplier` I need only 2 methods, but there can be some associated overhead, so I wrote `timeDirect` measuring one of the methods directly to see the overhead.

Obviously `timeDirect` doesn't depend on the parameter and should be invoked just once. Is there a way how to tell it caliper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In caliper 1.0 you'll be able to throw a `SkipThisScenarioException` any time you determine that your combination of params is not worth benchmarking.  It will cause Caliper to just skip over that combination, like it sounds.

Comment: Can you tell me when caliper 1.0 comes out? There are no changes in the public repo since one year ago.

Comment: Sounds like you're still looking in svn, but we moved to git a while ago:  https://code.google.com/p/caliper/source/list

Comment: The caliper 1.0 codebase is already runnable by simply updating to the latest code and setting a USE_CANARY_CALIPER=1 environment variable -- but it's a little not-ready-for-prime-time at the moment, which I expect to be in a much better state within 2 months.